# When are $\mathbb Z_m$ and $\mathbb Z_n$ homomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $m$ and $n$ be two given positive integers such that $m<n$. Then what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the groups $(\mathbb Z_m,+_m)$ and $(\mathbb Z_n,+_n)$ to be homomorphic under the map $\phi \colon \mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb Z_m$ such that $\phi(x)$ is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $m$, for each $x$ in $\mathbb Z_n$.

I know that if one of these integers is a divisor of the other, then the groups are homomorphic.

Comment: By homomorphic you mean there exists a non-trivial homomorphism between them?

Comment: What do you mean when you say two groups are homomorphic?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! Yes, of course, I mean that there exists a non-trivial homomorphism between them. In fact, I would like the conditions under whcih the remainder map becomes a homorphism form the group with the larger order to one with the smaller order. Can I make some alterations to my questions?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ if and only if $(m) \subset (n)$, which is equivalent to $n \mid m$. It's easy to see if you consider the canonical map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to both.

Comment: I'd suggest to rephrase this as “when is that map ... a homomorphism”.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of $\phi$ is not right: there is no Euclidean division defined on $\def\Z{\mathbf Z}\Z/n\Z$ (some elements like the class of $n-1$ have inverses, in which case exact division by them is possible, but in the contrary case no useful notion of division with remainder exists). Instead you mean to take a representative in $\Z$ of a class in $\Z/n\Z$, and apply Euclidean division by$~m$ to that representative. This defines a map $\Z/n\Z\to\Z/m\Z$ *only*
if the remainder of that division is *independent* of the choice of that representative. You can easily figure out when this happens, and if it does the resulting map is easily seen to be a homomorphism.

Comment: Then what about the map $\phi \colon Z_6 \to Z_2$ defined by the remainder of $x$ when divided by $2$, as in the division algorithm? In this case $2$ divides $6$. Can't we define such a map of $Z_9$ into $Z_2$, for example, by taking the former to be represented by the set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 8\}$?

Comment: The point of my answer is that no operation of Euclidean division by $2$ is defined in $\Z/6\Z$ (you can of course define one in whatever crazy way you like, but then you are on your own to prove any properties). In this case choosing a representative and _then_ doing Euclidean division gives a result independent of the choice, and allows defining a morphism $\Z/6\Z\to\Z/2\Z$. In the case of $\Z/9\Z$ the element $2$ is invertible (in the _ring_ $\Z/9\Z$), so division by it _is defined_, but with no place for a remainder. Trying to define a nonzero morphism $\Z/9\Z\to\Z/2\Z$ does not work.

Comment: If as you suggest you circumvent to problem of showing that the choice of representative does not matter (since it does matter for $\Z/9\Z$ when dividing by $2$) by forcing a particular choice of representative, then you will run into trouble showing the map defined using that is a homomorphism of groups. Try to prove it is a homomorphism, this is the best way to see where you need the freedom to choose representatives.